# Adding only ES2015 module support to Node

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to add to Node the functionality of import/export as it exists in ES6.

I know Babel can be used to gain all ES6 functionality, but what I wanna see is if there is a way I can use Babel to add only the import/export functionality and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/) plugin.

> This plugin transforms ES2015 modules to CommonJS.

Install it:

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs --save
```

Declare it in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

If you find yourself needing to `require` the default export of a module that declares its exports using the ES2015 module syntax, you will have to do the following:

```
var defaultExport = require('./es2015-module').default
```

To avoid this, install the [`babel-plugin-add-module-exports`](https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) plugin, and update your `.babelrc`:

```
npm install babel-plugin-add-module-exports --save
```

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

______

To use this Babel configuration in your application, use the [`babel-register` require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/).

In your application's entry file, for example:

```
// index.js
require('babel-register')
require('./app.js')
```

Then start using the ES2015 module syntax:

```
// app.js
import something from './something'
```

Comment: do i run node like always (node app.js) or some other way if i do that?

Comment: You would use [`babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/).

Comment: as in babel-register filename.js ?

Comment: @OmryRozenfeld No - read the documentation for the `babel-register` require hook. :-)

Comment: sorry for the ignorace but i cant seem to understand the flow here, could you somehow hint a bit more?

Comment: add-module-exports requires itself to be put before transform-es2015-modules-umd, https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports . Is there a reason why the opposite thing was made in .babelrc here?

Comment: @estus A mistake. Thanks :-)